# How do I invoke a COM method in C++ when the output parameter is a class?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, mfc

### Background

I'm a C# developer with almost zero experience with C++, and only a tiny bit more with COM. My colleague is a C++ developer with almost zero experience with .Net and not a lot with COM. We're trying to get his C++ MFC app to use a DLL I am writing in C# on .Net 3.5.

I was mostly following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C

However, I can't find any examples of a COM interface that returns an object instead of a simple type.

### The DLL

At the Assembly level I have `ComVisible(false)` because there are a great number of classes in the real DLL that will not be used from C++. This lets me use `ComVisible(true)` just on the classes and interfaces I want visible in COM.

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: ComVisible( false )]
[assembly: Guid( "59db8b2b-572d-42fc-83ae-36fe1a97695f" )]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "1.0.0.0" )]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion( "1.0.0.0" )]

namespace ComTest
{
    [Guid( "9600F16D-2ECA-446C-83C9-B15FD472D12D" )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    public interface ITestClass
    {
        ISerialInfo GetSerialInfo( string serial );
    }

    [Guid( "3C63AF8C-4730-4526-94C9-D8AA6805962A" )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    [ClassInterface( ClassInterfaceType.None )]
    public class TestClass : ITestClass
    {
        public ISerialInfo GetSerialInfo( string serial )
        {
            //Other properties excluded for brevity.
            return new SerialInfo
            {
                SerialNumber = serial
            };
        }
    }

    [Guid( "F2885515-EEE8-49B1-B795-B92955EFEF0D" )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    public interface ISerialInfo
    {
        string BomRevision { get; set; }
        string InteroperationStep { get; set; }
        bool IsValid { get; set; }
        string Job { get; set; }
        string JobSalesOrder { get; set; }
        int JobSalesOrderLine { get; set; }
        string MaterialStatus { get; set; }
        int OperationSequence { get; set; }
        string Organization { get; set; }
        string ParentSerialNumber { get; set; }
        string PartNumber { get; set; }
        string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        string State { get; set; }
    }

    [Guid( "D60020F1-823D-497E-A91D-427AEA1195C6" )]
    [ComVisible( true )]
    [ClassInterface( ClassInterfaceType.None )]
    public class SerialInfo : ISerialInfo
    {
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }
        public string BomRevision { get; set; }
        public string JobSalesOrder { get; set; }
        public int JobSalesOrderLine { get; set; }
        public int OperationSequence { get; set; }
        public string InteroperationStep { get; set; }
        public string ParentSerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string MaterialStatus { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### COM Registration

I use the following batch file to register the DLL for COM and generate a TLB file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil" /i ComTest.dll
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" ComTest.dll /tlb:ComTest.tlb
```

### Snippet of the TLH File

```cpp
virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetSerialInfo (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR serial,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct ISerialInfo * * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

### The MFC App

I have no idea what to pass in for the output parameter of this method. I've tried a couple of things, and I can get it to build, but not run. I don't know if I have to instantiate a concrete TestClass then cast it to an interface and pass in a pointer to it, or what. I'm at a loss here. I've done a lot of google searching, but couldn't find any examples showing COM returning more than just a string or an integer. I can get this to work just fine if my method returns an int.

I've excluded all of the boilerplate code.

```cpp
#import "C:\\Users\\Glazed\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ComTest\\ComTest\\bin\\Debug\\ComTest.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    ComTest::ITestClassPtr testClassPtr;

    HRESULT hRes = testClassPtr.CreateInstance(ComTest::CLSID_TestClass);

    if (hRes == S_OK)
    {
        //What goes here to initialize an entity to pass into the following method

        testClassPtr->GetSerialInfo( L"TE-006",  );
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pointer to the object.   It looks like there's a bunch of wrapping going on via #import, so it looks like the appropriate class would be `ComTest::ISerialInfoPtr`:

```
if (hRes == S_OK)
{
    ComTest::ISerialInfoPtr pInfo;
    hRes = testClassPtr->GetSerialInfo( L"TE-006", &pInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's working. I can debug the DLL project and have it run the C++ EXE and my breakpoint is being hit. However, the input parameter "serial" is coming through as an empty string instead of "TE-006". I don't suppose you have an equally easy answer to that, too. :) http://imgur.com/q84imEZ I changed the method to return the constant "Testing" and I can see that in C++ now.

Comment: I figured it out. I need to use an instance of ATL::CComBSTR. I.e., `ATL::CComBSTR serialInput = L"TE-006";`